# Android install source

Tags: android, apk, google-play, amazon-appstore

Is it possible to get the source of install from an `Android` app?

I mean, I want to see, if the app is installed from the `Play Store`, `Amazon Appstore` or via executing an APK.

PS: I think to see it while my app crashes and I was able to send an bug report, that my app was installed via `Play Store`. How do I get this value?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The PackageManager class supplies the [getInstallerPackageName](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstallerPackageName%28java.lang.String%29) method that will tell you the package name of whatever installed the package you specify. Side-loaded apps will not contain a value.

The latest version of the Amazon store finally sets PackageManager.getInstallerPackageName() to "`com.amazon.venezia`" as well to contrast with Google Play's "`com.android.vending`".

Source: [How to know an application is installed from google play or side-load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809438/how-to-know-an-application-is-installed-from-google-play-or-side-load) For an Example: [getInstallerPackageName returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12593621/getinstallerpackagename-returns-null)

Answer (score 3):

At present (16/01/2022) code:

```
val s = applicationContext.getPackageManager().getInstallerPackageName(applicationContext.getPackageName())
```

works fine for Android 11 in GooglePlay, and get "com.android.vending".

Answer (score 3):

Here's a util function (in Kotlin) that you can add to your code:

```
/**
 * Retrieves the name of the app responsible for the installation of this app.
 * This can help in identifying which market this app was installed from or whether the user
 * sideloaded it using an APK (Package Installer).
 */
fun getAppInstaller(context: Context): String {
    val appContext = context.applicationContext

    val installerPackageName = try {
        val appPackageManager = appContext.packageManager
        val appPackageName = appContext.packageName

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
            appPackageManager.getInstallSourceInfo(appPackageName).installingPackageName
        else
            appPackageManager.getInstallerPackageName(appPackageName)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        "--"
    }

    return when (installerPackageName) {
        "com.android.vending" -> "Google Play Store"
        "com.amazon.venezia" -> "Amazon AppStore"
        "com.huawei.appmarket" -> "Huawei AppGallery"
        "com.google.android.packageinstaller" -> "Package Installer"
        else -> installerPackageName ?: "Unknown"
    }
}
```

I used the answers of the great folks here in this StackOverflow question and others to create the above function. You can call this function passing it a context and then maybe set the return as a custom key in Crashlytics or record it for analytics or whatever you want.

Answer (score 2):

Use [getInstallerPackageName](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstallerPackageName%28java.lang.String%29).

This stores the packageName of what installed the application.

- Google Play: "com.android.vending"
- Amazon Appstore: "com.amazon.venezia"