# Lock the app to prevent the app from being installed on other people's devices

Tags: android, android-studio, security

How can I make **my app** so that if the user copies **it** installed on his device and sends **it** to his friends, his friends can't install the app?

I want users to be able to download **my app** from the `market` ***only***.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23262979/android-install-source

Comment: @DarShan thanks.
but `PackageManager.getInstallerPackageName(String packageName)`, need to `INSTALL_PACKAGES` permission; and it permission not grant by Android.
Because it permission is protected. And I don't know how to get it from Android.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best ways is to let anyone install app and then enable app features using in-app purchase.

If your application is online, you can submit user IP at sign up and block other IPs from accessing user accounts or better define a count limit for IPs of each account.

I don't think there's any way to prevent app installation on other user phones.

Comment: Thanks. If I have to and can't find a way, I'll convert the app to an in-app purchase.